# SQL Server: how to find the record where a field is X for the first time and there are no later records where it isn't

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I tried for quite some time now but cannot figure out how to best do this without using cursors. What I want to do (in SQL Server) is:

- Find the earliest (by *Date*) record where *Criterion*=1 AND NOT followed by *Criterion*=0 for each *Name* and *Category*.

Or expressed differently:

- Find the *Date* when *Criterion* turned 1 and not turned 0 again afterwards (for each *Name* and *Category*).

Some sort of CTE would seem to make sense I guess but that's not my strong suit unfortunately. So I tried nesting queries to find the latest record where *Criterion*=0 and then select the next record if there is one but I'm getting incorrect results. Another challenge with this is returning a record where there are only records with *Criterion*=1 for a *Name* and *Category*.

Here's the sample data:

```
Name    Category    Criterion     Date
------------------------------------------------    
Bob     Cat1        1             22.11.16 08:54   X 
Bob     Cat2        0             21.02.16 02:29    
Bob     Cat3        1             22.11.16 08:55    
Bob     Cat3        0             22.11.16 08:56    
Bob     Cat4        0             21.06.12 02:30    
Bob     Cat4        0             18.11.16 08:18    
Bob     Cat4        1             18.11.16 08:19    
Bob     Cat4        0             22.11.16 08:20    
Bob     Cat4        1             22.11.16 08:50   X    
Bob     Cat4        1             22.11.16 08:51    
Hannah  Cat1        1             22.11.16 08:54   X    
Hannah  Cat2        0             21.02.16 02:29    
Hannah  Cat3        1             22.11.16 08:55
Hannah  Cat3        0             22.11.16 08:56
```

The rows with an **X** after the row are the ones I want to retrieve.

It's probably not all that complicated in the end...

Comment: Ideally I'd also get a null record for Name and Category if there is no such record (e.g. Bob/Cat2, Bob/Cat3, Hannah/Cat2, Hannah/Cat3, Hannah/Cat4)

Comment: By "not followed" do you mean immediately followed? e.g. 1-->0 or do you also consider 1-->1-->0 as 1 followed by 0 (for the most left 1)?

Comment: yes @DuduMarkovitz, the left-most 1 is followed by a 0 as well. Indirectly but followed nonetheless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the name, category, and date:

```
select name, category, min(date)
from t
where criterion = 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.name = t.name and t2.category = t.category and
                        t2.criterion = 0 and t2.date >= t.date
                 )
group by name, category;
```

There are fancier ways to get this information, but this is a relatively simple method.

Actually, the fancier ways aren't particularly complicated:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when date > maxdate_0 or maxdate_0 is NULL then date end) over (partition by name, category) as mindate_1
      from (select t.*,
                   max(case when criterion = 0 then date end) over (partition by name, category) as maxdate_0
            from t
           ) t
      where criterion = 1
     ) t
where mindate_1 = date;
```

EDIT:

SQL Fiddle doesn't seem to be working these days.  The following is working for me (using Postgres):

```
with t(name, category, criterion, date) as (
    values ('Bob', 'Cat1', 1, '2016-11-16 08:54'),
           ('Bob', 'Cat2', 0, '2016-02-21 02:29'), 
           ('Bob', 'Cat3', 1, '2016-11-16 08:55'), 
           ('Bob', 'Cat3', 0, '2016-11-16 08:56'), 
           ('Bob', 'Cat4', 0, '2012-06-21 02:30'), 
           ('Bob', 'Cat4', 0, '2016-11-18 08:18'), 
           ('Bob', 'Cat4', 1, '2016-11-18 08:19'),
           ('Bob', 'Cat4', 0, '2016-11-22 08:20'),    
           ('Bob', 'Cat4', 1, '2016-11-22 08:50'),  
           ('Bob', 'Cat4', 1, '2016-11-22 08:51'), 
           ('Hannah', 'Cat1', 1, '2016-11-22 08:54'),    
           ('Hannah', 'Cat2', 0, '2016-02-21 02:29'),   
           ('Hannah', 'Cat3', 1, '2016-11-22 08:55'),
           ('Hannah', 'Cat3', 0, '2016-11-22 08:56')
          )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when date > maxdate_0 or maxdate_0 is NULL then date end) over (partition by name, category) as mindate_1
      from (select t.*,
                   max(case when criterion = 0 then date end) over (partition by name, category) as maxdate_0
            from t
           ) t
      where criterion = 1
     ) t
where mindate_1 = date;
```

Comment: I tried running your second query, it's throwing an error on `where mindate_1 = mindate`, saying mindate wasn't declared

Comment: For Bob/Cat4 this returns `18.11.16 08:19` but since there is a 0 for `22.11.16 08:20`, followed by further 1's, the correct result should be  `22.11.16 08:50` (second to last record for Bob/Cat4)

Comment: Also it returns a record (`22.11.16 08:55`) for Bob/Cat3 when there should be none.

Comment: sorry, disregard my last comments, this is working just fine!

Answer (score 1):

How about a left join, and filter the NULLs?

```
SELECT yt.Name, yt.Category, yt.Criterion, MIN(yt.Date) AS Date
FROM YourTable yt
LEFT JOIN YourTable lj ON lj.Name = yt.Name AND lj.Category = yt.Category AND
                          lj.Criterion != yt.Criterion AND lj.Date > yt.Date
WHERE yt.Criterion = 1 AND lj.Name IS NULL
GROUP BY yt.Name, yt.Category, yt.Criterion
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work - returns zero rows for me... Might be me though

Answer (score 1):

Modified answer

```
select      name,category
           ,min (date)      as date

from       (select      name,category,criterion,date

                       ,min (criterion) over 
                        (
                            partition by    name,category 
                            order by        date 
                            rows            between current row and unbounded following
                        ) as min_following_criterion

            from        t
            ) t

where       criterion      = 1
        and (   min_following_criterion <> 0
            or  min_following_criterion is null
            )

group by    name,category
```

Comment: Thanks but no, not only adjacent follows but any following 0

Comment: @Peete, see modified answer

Answer (score 1):

there are ton's of ways of doing it especially with Window Functions.  The NOT EXISTS, or Anti Join are 2 of the better methods but just for fun here is one of the fancier (to steal Gordon's term) ways of doing it with Window Functions:

```
;WITH cte AS  (
    SELECT
       Name
       ,Category
       ,CASE WHEN Criterion = 1 THEN Date END as Criterion1Date
       ,MAX(CASE WHEN Criterion = 0 THEN Date END) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Category) as MaxDateCriterion0
    FROM
       Table
)

SELECT
    Name
    ,Category
    ,MIN(Criterion1Date) as Date
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    ISNULL(MaxDateCriterion0,'1/1/1900') < Criterion1Date
GROUP BY
    Name
    ,Category
```

Or as a Derived Table if you don't like cte, the only difference is basically nesting the cte in the from clause.

```
SELECT
    Name
    ,Category
    ,MIN(Criterion1Date) as Date
FROM
    (
       SELECT
          Name
          ,Category
          ,CASE WHEN Criterion = 1 THEN Date END as Criterion1Date
          ,MAX(CASE WHEN Criterion = 0 THEN Date END) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Category) as MaxDateCriterion0
       FROM
          Table
    ) t
WHERE
    ISNULL(MaxDateCriterion0,'1/1/1900') < Criterion1Date
GROUP BY
    Name
    ,Category
```

Comment: For Bob/Cat4 this returns `18.11.16 08:19` but since there is a 0 for `22.11.16 08:20`, followed by further 1's, the correct result should be  `22.11.16 08:50` (second to last record for Bob/Cat4). Same as Gordon's reply, maybe my question wasn't clear.

Comment: Also it returns a record (`22.11.16 08:55`) for Bob/Cat3 when there should be none.  Also it returns a record (`22.11.16 08:55`) for Bob/Cat3 when there should be none.

Comment: sorry, disregard my last comments, this is working just fine!